# Methods for augmenting binary datasets

Tags: data-augmentation, smote, boosting

I have a small (~100 samples) dataset with roughly 20 features which are mostly binary, and a few are numeric (~5). I wanted to use methods for augmenting the training set and see if I can get better test accuracy. What methods/code can I use for augmenting binary datasets?

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Metropolis–Hastings sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) if multi-dimensional, or else [Adaptive rejection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling#Adaptive_rejection_sampling), unless you've already tried.